# get a lot of HTML pages with python url requests

Tags: python, html, httprequest

I am trying to dowload a big amount of HTML pages from a certain website, with the following python code using "requests" package:

```
FROM = 547495 
TO = 570000
for page_number in range(FROM, TO):
    url = DEFAULT_URL + str(page_number)
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
            with open(str(page_number) + ".html", "wb") as file: 
                file.write(response.content)
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

I put a sleep(0.5) command in order that the web server will not think it is a DDOS attack.

after about 20,000 pages, I started getting only 403 forbiden http status code, and I can't anymore download pages.
But, if I try to open the same pages in my browser It opens well, so I guess the web server did not block me.
does someone has an Idea what caused it? and how can I handle it?

thank you

Comment: `DEFAULT_URL` realize that you are scraping it and block you. Try to use proxy.

Comment: Also please read their TOS and perhaps find an API. It is REALLY irritating when ppl scrape you and you have an API

Comment: you can change headers?

Comment: It's probably expecting you to use some headers.

Comment: @mplungjan they don't have an API.

Comment: @diggusbickus where to change headers? in the http request?

Answer (score 0):

Make it look like it's your browser using headers, and set a cookie ID if it requires a session, here is an example. You can retrieve values of headers from inspecting "Network" tab in your browser when visiting the pages.

```py
with requests.session() as sess:
        sess.headers["User-Agent"]= "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:81.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/81.0"
        sess.get(url)
        sess.headers["Cookie"] = "eZSESSID={}".format(sess.cookies.get("eZSESSID"))
        for page_number in range(FROM, TO):
            if response.status_code == 200:
                with open(str(page_number) + ".html", "wb") as file: 
                    file.write(response.content)
            time.sleep(0.5)
```